# Call String subSequence() after convert Stringbuffer toString()

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I found in a existing Java program code the following snip:

```
StringBuffer b = new Stringbuffer()
// fill the StringBuffer
(...)

String temp = b.toString();
return temp.subSequence(0, b.toString().length() - 1);
```

I don't understand why they done a `subSequence` from position 0 to the end...
Is the format of a StringBuilder after the convertition into a String that ugly?

They, they wrote this code aren't in my company anymore, so I can't ask them...

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: I'll tell you the most typical reason why: in the loop, some list elements are joined into a string with a delimiter. The naïve version of that just appends the delimiter after each member, so the result must be fixed up by removing the very last character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to strip one char from the end, note that all Java standard library classes follow a convention about start / end index parameters, star is inclusive and end is exclusive. Also I agree that the code is ugly, it should be

```
...
return b.subSequence(0, b.length() - 1);
```

it's shorter and also more efficient. Also StringBuffer is a legacy class you can replace it with faster StringBuilder

Comment: So directly to the StringBuffer? And what is `sb`?

Comment: sb was supposed to be b. my fault. StringBuffer.substring creates a String that we need immediately

Answer (score 1):

The subsequence:

```
temp.subSequence(0, b.toString().length() - 1);
```

is stripping the last character, and not returning the same string.

Comment: Yes but why? This make no sense... Is the last character something special in a String Builder? Because the last character that i append to the string builder shouldn't get stripped

Comment: @user2413035. If you don't want to strip last character, then just return `temp`. No need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    b.append("a");
    b.append("b");
    b.append("c");
    String temp = b.toString();        
    System.out.println(temp); // now out put is abc
```

If some one want to subString this you can subString this as follows.

```
    System.out.println(temp.subSequence(0, b.toString().length() - 1));
    System.out.println(temp.substring(0, b.toString().length() - 1));
```

Comment: After the substring, the output is only `ab`?

Comment: yes it is both subSequence and substring will give same out put.

Answer (score 0):

It is same as `substring()` method.So can use either one of them.
Accodring to [StringBuffer doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#subSequence)

> An invocation of this method of the form
>    sb.subSequence(begin, end)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>    sb.substring(begin, end)
>   This method is provided so that this class can implement the CharSequence interface.